# Blocking Scoped outputs

Tags: java, class, oop, block

I dont know whether this question has been asked before or not .I searched but couldn't find any duplicate question. If you find any related question please mention the link.

```
public class Exp 
{
    Exp()
    {
         System.out.println("Hello");      //3
    }
    {    System.out.println("Hello")};    //1
    {    static{System.out.print("x");}   //2
}
```

The order of printing of messages is 2,1,3.

What are the significance of these lines 1 & 2 and why that exec order

Comment: What order of printing? This code doesn't even run...

Comment: Static content is initialized first before the object is constructed.

Comment: @Zong Zheng Li That is incomplete piece of code  . Just  initialize the class Exp.

Comment: but what the blocked statements actually mean @PM77-1

Comment: It's well described in [Thinking in Java](http://sina.sharif.edu/~abolhassani/courses/ap/tij3.pdf).  See pages 111 - 114.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line "1" is an *instance initializer*, which runs when an object is first created, before any constructors are called.

Line "2" is a *static initializer*, which runs when a class is first loaded, before any objects are created.

[Section 12.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) specifies when instance initializers are run:

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new
>   object using the following procedure:
>
> Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter
>   variables for this constructor invocation.
>
> If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation
>   (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then
>   evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>   recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>   invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>   for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
>
> This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>   this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>   constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>   superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>   process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these
>   same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly,
>   then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise,
>   continue with step 4.
>
> **Execute the instance initializers** and instance variable initializers
>   for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers
>   to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in
>   which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If
>   execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then
>   no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes
>   abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
>
> **Execute the rest of the body of this constructor.** If that execution
>   completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the
>   same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

(emphasis mine)

The rest of the body of the constructor is executed after the instance initializer.

Answer (score 1):

static blocks of a class are executed during class loading along with constants (static final members).  3 is invoked when the object is instantiated.
For you to understand better debug the code through your IDE to understand the sequence of execution.

Comment: Okay, and why would we care about your blog?

Comment: Please do not advertise your blog unless it is very relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok Gotcha, Sorry new here.  Will take care of this in future.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

A static initialization block is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword. Here is an example:

```
static {
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. **The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.**

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the execution order is, in non-static block you might want to use static members, but in static block you cannot use non-static members. So it makes sense to execute static block first.
non-static block allows you to abstract the code that every constructor needs to execute, therefore it gets executed before constructor.

More detailed order of execution:

1.static block of superclass

2.static block of this class

3.non-static block of superclass

4.constructor of superclass

5.non-static block of this class

6.constructor of this class